# Cant get more than 600 tweets using tweepy search api

Tags: python, twitter, data-science, tweepy

noofitem = 1000
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=['#iphone11, -filter:retweets'],since='2019-11-14',lang='en',tweet_mode='extended',retweeted=False).items(noofitem)
i = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets] #Tweet text

I am trying to get about 1000 tweets using tweepy. But the max tweets I get are around 600. Changing the date does not work. Any modification or other workarounds will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the
> Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all
> Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

Please refer to this link for more information: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#help-methods

Probably you will need to set up a Stream to get the amount of data you need.

Comment: thanks .. will check it out. I did setup a stream. was wondering for the search API.